# ajax - incremental load of elements from one file

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I've got an index.html with a container in which I want to load content via ajax on click. It looks like this:

```
<div id="loadcontent"></div>
<div id="more">Load More</div>
```

And there's only one content file with a lot of divs:

```
<div id="1" class="content">One</div>
<div id="2" class="content">Two</div>
<div id="3" class="content">Three</div>
<div id="4" class="content">Four</div>
<div id="5" class="content">Five</div>
<div id="6" class="content">Six</div>
<div id="7" class="content">Seven</div>
<div id="8" class="content">Eight</div>
<div id="9" class="content">Nine</div>
<div id="10" class="content">Ten</div>
<div id="11" class="content">Eleven</div>
<div id="12" class="content">Twelve</div>
```

Here's the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var countItem = 0;

    $('#more').click(function(){
        countItem ++;
        $('<div/>').appendTo('#loadcontent').load('content.html #' + countItem)
            .hide()
            .fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

For now it loads just one div when the load more button is clicked, cause it counts the ids.

Is it possible to load the next three ore more divs using ajax and append them to divs which already have been loaded? If yes, how can I get this working?
For example: first click: 1-3, second click: 1-6, third click: 1-9, etc...

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I don't want to load the content at once and then showing it up using `.show()` or something similar. It should be an ajax request for each click.

Comment: Just make one request and store the response in a variable. Then add to the container each click. Makes no sense requesting the same file over and over.

Comment: You could have the server-side file generate only 3 elements at a time. You pass in the number of total elements received and then make an ajax to get 3 elements after that

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to load one file which contains all content and then show it partically, you don't need to make request for each part, just load all content at once and show it when needed.

I made an example with a partial display of content by the click of a button, see working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zmjavz56/):

```
$(window).ready(function() {
  var $contentContainer = $('.loadcontent');
  var lastShownIndex = 0; // id of latest shown div
  var showPerClick = 3;
  var elementsCount = 0; // total available elements count 

  // function to show elements with passed ids
  var showElements = function(ids) {
    ids.forEach(function(id) {
        $contentContainer.find('#' + id).fadeIn(500);
    });
  }
  // function to generate array [start, start + 1, ..., end]
  var range = function(start, end) {
    return Array.apply(null, Array(end - start + 1)).map(function (_, i) {
        return i + start;
    });
  }
  // function to generate array of unshown divs
  var generateIds = function() {
    if (lastShownIndex >= elementsCount) return [];
    var ids = range(lastShownIndex + 1, Math.min(lastShownIndex + showPerClick, elementsCount));
    lastShownIndex += showPerClick;
    return ids;
  }
  // load content into container
  $contentContainer.load('content.html', function() {
    elementsCount = $contentContainer.find('.content').length;
    showElements(generateIds()); // show elements after page load
  });
  // show items partially by clicking a button
  $('#more').click(function() {
    showElements(generateIds());
    if (lastShownIndex >= elementsCount) { // hide button when no elements are available
        $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This could be a solution, but: loading the content at once is something i want to avoid with that, because those divs could contain images with big file sizes and there are a lot divs. My purpose is to save bandwith and to request an amount of content if desired.

Comment: If all the content is in one file, then there is no way to force jQuery to load the file by parts, it will in any case be loaded entirely. You need to either split the content into different files, or write a server-side script that will only give portions of the file.

Comment: So, does that mean when those div- elements do not appear in the DOM, like they do using the code provided in my question, they are still entirely loaded on visit? I'm curious about that.

Comment: Yes, you can look into browser's developer tools and on Network tab you will see that the content file (with all it's divs) is downloaded entirely each time. But pictures are loaded only from the necessary div.

Comment: @Anton can simplify all this using `slice()`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you only make one request and store the request promise in a variable. Use [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to filter new items to add each time

```
$(function() {
  var contentPromise = null,
    itemsPerClick = 3,
    startIndex = 0,
    $moreButton = $('#more');

 $moreButton.click(function() {
    getContent()
      .then(insertContent)
      .fail(function() {
        console.error("Failed request!")
      });
  });

  function getContent() {
    if (!contentPromise) {
      // store request promise
      contentPromise = $.get('content.html').then(function(resp) {
        // return jQuery object that can easily be sliced
        return $(resp).filter('div');
      })
    }
    return contentPromise;
  }

  function insertContent($content) {
    var endIndex = startIndex + itemsPerClick,
      $newItems = $content.slice(startIndex, endIndex);

    $('<div>').append($newItems)
      .appendTo('#loadcontent')
      .hide()
      .fadeIn(1000);

    // increment start 
    startIndex = endIndex;
    // hide button when none left
    if (startIndex >= $content.length) {
      $moreButton.hide()
    }
  }
});
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/eBqxiZ9cz6Ln679ycHSf?p=preview)**